# Problem with product collection and configurable products

Tags: magento-1.8, product, configurable-product, collection-filtering, product-collection

Hi i have this code:

```
                //shop the look product code
                $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
                // Select which fields to load into the product
                // * will load all fields but it is possible to pass an array of
                // select fields to load
                $products->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCatId()));
                $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                $products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
                // Ensure the product is visible
                $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => 1));
                // Ensure the product is enabled
                $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
                $products->addAttributeToFilter('featured_products', 'si');
                $products->getSelect()->limit(1);
                // Load the collection
                $products->load();
```

it will take all products from the passed catedory id with a filter on featured_products. 
it works fine but only with simple products, it don’t load configurable products from the category!!

it’s a magento bug i think, there is a solution to retrive configurable products too?

Comment: Stupid question but does the configurable products have this `featured_products` as well? On a side note: please don't use `addAttributeToSelect('*')`, it's a performance killer

Comment: yes all products have the attribute and the value is set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **catalog_product_entity**. Essentially you are interested in the **type_id** column. Now because it is located in the base table for the entity you should use **addFieldToFilter** instead of **addAttributeToFilter** http://www.creare.co.uk/magento-product-collection-bible

Comment: works like a charm thanks!! replaced **addAttributeToFilter** with **addFieldToFilter** and now it takes simple and configurable products!

Comment: Glad to hear that!